вылетает приложение при работе с EditText
editText.setText("text");
strEditText = editText.getText().toString();

При вызове любой из этих команд вылетает приложение
LogCat:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tstu, PID: 25911
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tstu/com.example.tstu.scheduleSet}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4049)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8348)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.example.tstu.scheduleSet.onCreate(scheduleSet.java:88)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8577)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8541)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1437)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3884)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4049) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8348) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028)


Я так понимаю, вы новичек?
Тогда дам совет.
Изучайте сразу kotlin и compose.
У меня 12 лет опыта на андроид, но я уже забыл, когда в последний раз работал с java и view

Прежде чем работать с переменной, нужно присвоить ей значение.
В случае с UI-элементами нужно установить разметку на экран, потом найти нужный виджет:
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
editText = findViewById(R.id.your_edit_id_in_layout);

И только после этого вы можете работать с editText.
Если у вас всё так, но ошибка та же - значит что-то не так с разметкой.

@clay Если ответ помог решить проблему, и, таким образом, является правильным, вы должны отметить его как верный. При этом у автора ответа повысятся баллы репутации.

    try {
            editText.setText("text");
            strEditText = editText.getText().toString();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){}


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Можно конечно и так обрабатывать исключения, но лучше всё же выяснить, почему код выполняется, когда editText ещё не проинициализирован.
